# Go back to to previous page ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im having an issue of going back to the previous page. The page i want to go back to had a few radio buttons which you had to select, after this you went to the next page which is the current page which then you can select certain things BUT I want to be able to go back to the previous page and the original selections for that page still be selected.

Anyway i could do this if so how?????

Comment: Are you talking about browser back button?

Comment: Look at state management, i.e. ViewState: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: Show us some codebehind, especially PageLoad method.

Comment: Is this MVC or webforms?

Comment: Webforms. and i have tried veiwstates but they dont keep the selected buttons

Answer (score 2):

You can do a real basic back button with the help of JavaScript.

```
window.history.go(-1);
```

which will take you back to the previous page.

Comment: But you are depending on the browsers cache for remebering form input, which I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: @zeebonk very true, hence why I said real basic ;-)

Comment: Yes I saw, but because the OP asked specificly about remembering form values I thought it would be nice to note this behaviour explicit :)

Answer (score 1):

By default in ASP.NET state of controls is stored in ViewState, so it should be the same as user left them.

It is probably some view-state issue.

Go to your codebehind and check PageLoad method. If you are creating or setting radios in PageLoad, you do not want to re-init them every post-back.

```
if (!IsPostBack){
 // your init here
}
```